# How to lock (Mutex) in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mutex

There are external resources (accessing available inventories through an API) that can only be accessed one thread at a time.

My problems are:

1. NodeJS server handles requests concurrently, we might have multiple requests at the same time trying to reserve inventories.
2. If I hit the inventory API concurrently, then it will return duplicate available inventories
3. Therefore, I need to make sure that I am hitting the inventory API one thread at a time
4. There is no way for me to change the inventory API (legacy), therefore I must find a way to synchronize my nodejs server.

Note:

- There is only one nodejs server, running one process, so I only need to synchronize the requests within that server
- Low traffic server running on express.js

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module's [queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) and set its `concurrency` parameter to `1`. That way, you can put as many tasks in the queue as you need to run, but they'll only run one at a time.

The queue would look something like:

```
var inventoryQueue = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
    // use the values in "task" to call your inventory API here
    // pass your results to "callback" when you're done
}, 1);
```

Then, to make an inventory API request, you'd do something like:

```
var inventoryRequestData = { /* data you need to make your request; product id, etc. */ };
inventoryQueue.push(inventoryRequestData, function(err, results) {
    // this will be called with your results
});
```