# how to make sure that transactions happen one at a time

Tags: node.js

I have a web server that allows users to fetch items from a server.

Once that item is fetched it is deleted. And only one user should possibly be able to fetch that item.

I'm currently running my nodejs server on a mysql database. Is this something that nodejs already takes care of, or do i have to figure out a way to make sure that these transactions happen one at a time. If this is something that isn't automatically taken care of, then are there any frameworks that take care of that?

Comment: What do you mean "one at a time"?  web servers typically process transactions from many users.  We could help you a lot more specifically and probably give you much, much better advice if you showed us your code so we could see exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually begin and end transactions.

Here is example code for MySQL:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'YOUR_USERNAME',
      password : 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
      database : 'DB_NAME'
    }
);

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

/* Begin transaction */
connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  connection.query('INSERT INTO names SET name=?', "sameer", function(err, result) {
    if (err) { 
      connection.rollback(function() {
        throw err;
      });
    }

    var log = result.insertId;

    connection.query('INSERT INTO log SET logid=?', log, function(err, result) {
      if (err) { 
        connection.rollback(function() {
          throw err;
        });
      }  
      connection.commit(function(err) {
        if (err) { 
          connection.rollback(function() {
            throw err;
          });
        }
        console.log('Transaction Complete.');
        connection.end();
      });
    });
  });
});
/* End transaction */
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for lock or mutex with nodejs, Here is an answer to similar topic : [How to lock (Mutex) in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613227/how-to-lock-mutex-in-nodejs)