# Wait for data to be written in POST in nodejs json-server

Tags: node.js, nodes, json-server

I am using the json-server module to create a server that accepts POSTS, GET from a json file.

I see that on a POST, the data is being written to the JSON file, as expected. Is there a way for me to wait for the data to be written before calling another function that acts on the data?

```
server.use((req, res, next) => {
      if (req.method === 'POST') {          
            startCol.masterProc();
      }
})
```

The masterProc function works on the json file, but it seems to be called before the data is actually persisted to the json file. This might be a nodejs question, but could you please help me with actually waiting for the persistence before a function call?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lock (Mutex) in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613227/how-to-lock-mutex-in-nodejs)

Comment: Or possibly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145749/locking-on-an-object

Comment: Can we use async module within the server.use function?

Comment: who's calling this endpoint? Who writes to the file? Maybe don't call the endpoint until you finish writing? Need more code.

Answer (score 1):

The middleware you created intercepts the request before it gets to your db.json, so that's why when calling `startCol.masterProc()` the data is not there yet.

I believe you'll need to let the request pass through (that is, remove `server.use()`) and put your code in the router.render() method, like so:

```
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json')
router.render = (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {          
    startCol.masterProc();
  }      
}
```

But just out of curiosity, what happens if you call `next()` on your server.use right before calling `startCol.masterProc()`? Like so:

```
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  next();
  if (req.method === 'POST') {          
    startCol.masterProc();
  }
})
```